# I'm trying to access to my localhost server from my Android Emulator and i'm getting an ECONNREFUSED error

Tags: android

I try to get into the localhost server from android simulator and I can not. What should I do to get in?

Answer (score 0):

Use the IP address 10.0.2.2 instead of localhost

Further Read This 
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html